# git without repo directory

Tags: git, github, repository

Do git services (github, gitlab, gitea, etc.) support directly linking to a single file, should there only be one in the directory?

Say I setup github.com/user/file.txt as a repository, is it possible to only display the file directly rather than showing the whole list for only one file to appear? Basically only showing what would be displayed, had the user already clicked on that file.

I think I remember seeing something like this on github years ago but can't remember what it was about.

I've tried naming a directory github.com/user/file.py but it still shows the whole links page.
This is also quite rare, so searching it up only shows results for downloading specific files from directories...

Comment: I know that README.md will be rendered on the page of the repo. Other than that, I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I could've sworn it's possible, but thanks for the comment

Comment: Ré you talking about github gist? https://gist.github.com/ But even that it is a repository...

Comment: Yes - gists! Do you know if this is possible on gitea? I've got an account with heaps of single file repos I'd love to see in this format

Comment: AFAIK, No. There were [discussions](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/693) in the project, but they were closed as "not gitea mission".

Comment: You might also want to leave your +1 on https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/16670